# How to Mutate Flask's requests.args - ImmutableMultiDict

Tags: python, flask

I have a query parameter that is used in most of my APIs.

In the `@app.beforerequest` decorator, I would like to pop this query parameter from `request.args`, do something with it, and then prevent this query parameter from being accessible in the route function.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    foo = request.args.pop('foo')

@app.get('/')
def home():
    # foo parameter is no longer accessible in the route function
    assert 'foo' not in request.args
```

---

Given that `request.args` is an `ImmutableMultiDict`, `pop` of course does not work.

Neither is it OK to set `request.args` for example: `request.args = {k: v for k, v in request.args if k != 'foo'}`.

One option is to set the `parameter_storage_class` to `MultiDict`:

```
class MyRequest(Request):
    parameter_storage_class = MultiDict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.request_class = MyRequest
```

However, I am not clear what are the consequences of using MultiDict instead of ImmutableMultiDict. The docs present the following note without elaborating on the reason why:

> It possible to use mutable structures, but this is not recommended.